# Jersey HTTP Response return json value

Tags: java, jersey

```
public class Dto {
    private boolean flag;
    private String code;
    private String message;
    private Object data;
    ......
}
```

It is a generic return format.

```
@GET
@Path("/test2")
public Response appLogin2() {
    Dto dto = new Dto();
    Device device = new Device();
    device.setAreaName("NewYork");
    dto.setData(device);
    dto.setFlag(true);
    Response res = Response.status(Status.OK).entity(dto).build();
    return res;
}
```

But now its return value is

```
{
    "data": "com.gmi.its.itsmain.model.Device@7067fd1f",
    "flag": true
}
```

How can I get that return value

```
{
    "data": {
            "areaName": "NewYork"
        },
    "flag": true
}
```

I user springboot can get that return value.

Comment: Perhaps [HATEOAS](https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS) is what you are looking for

Comment: Use Jackson as your JSON provider. You are probably using MOXy, which will just call toString() on unknown objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a class for that `data` property. Currently, it is being read as an Object, which means that the serializer doesn't know what to expect about it. The only thing that the serializer can do is calling the Object's toString() method, which outputs `className@hashCode`.

Try something like this:

```
public class Dto {
  private boolean flag;
  private String code;
  private String message;
  private Device data;
  ......
}
```

If you are not sure about the class that you will use for the `data` field, you should create an interface that all these possible classes extend from.

Comment: But it can work right in SpringBoot SpringMVC,just private Object data.

Answer (score 0):

String jsonString = JSON.toJSONString(dto);
return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(jsonString).build();

I did it this way now